# In bash, how do I join N parameters together as a space separated string

Tags: string, bash, arguments

I'm trying to write a function that takes *n* parameters and joins them into a string.

In Perl it would be

```
my $string = join(' ', @ARGV);
```

but in bash I don't know how to do it

```
function()
{
    ??
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `function` keyword is an extension that makes your code gratuitously incompatible with POSIX (as compared to many of bash's other extensions which actually add value); it isn't actually required to declare a function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check the `bash` man page for the entry for '*' under Special Parameters.

```
join () {
    echo "$*"
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the first character of `$IFS` is used for the separator.

Comment: Actually the correct solution is `"$@"` if you need to handle quoted arguments.

Comment: The goal here is to collapse all the arguments into a single string, so the choice of `$*` or `$@` doesn't matter. Or rather, it's up to the consumer of `join` to quote the result, regardless of which parameter is used to access the args.

Comment: Quoting can be used to protect other special characters, too, not just single whitespace characters.

Comment: "join" may intend /usr/bin/join, so "spjoin" might be a safer name

Answer (score 9):

For the immediate question, [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12283551/900873) (`"$*"`) is easiest, but as an example of how to do it accessing each argument in turn:

```
func(){
    str=
    for i in "$@"; do 
        str="$str $i"
    done
    echo ${str# }
}
```

Comment: You should perhaps declare `local str` and `local i` just to be on the safe side.  `for i; do` defaults to processing `"$@"` but that's obviously just a shorthand.

Answer (score 9):

This one behaves like Perl `join`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sticker() {
  delim=$1      # join delimiter
  shift
  oldIFS=$IFS   # save IFS, the field separator
  IFS=$delim
  result="$*"
  IFS=$oldIFS   # restore IFS
  echo $result
}

sticker , a b c d efg
```

The above outputs:

```
a,b,c,d,efg
```

Comment: use `local IFS="$delim"` and you don't need to worry about having to restore it.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to perreal's answer, but with a subshell:

```
function strjoin () (IFS=$1; shift; echo "$*");
strjoin : 1 '2 3' 4
1:2 3:4
```

Perl's join can separate with more than one character and is quick enough to use from bash
(directly or with an alias or function wrapper)

```
perl -E 'say join(shift, @ARGV)'  ', '   1 '2 3' 4
1, 2 3, 4
```