# Bash function only processes first argument, even when "$@" is used

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm using a terminal program called espeak to convert a string of words into International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA). The main command is:

```
espeak -v fr --ipa "<string of words>"
```

Note that the text itself should be in quotations, since `espeak -v fr --ipa "Je suis"` will give the correct IPA transcription, but `espeak -v fr --ipa Je suis` will only give the transcription for "Je".

To avoid retyping the same commands every time, I defined the following function in my `.bashrc`:

```
function fr {
    espeak -v fr --ipa "$@"
}
```

However, when I run `fr Je suis` (without quotations) in my terminal, I only get the result for "Je", even though I have  nested the input argument `$@` in quotations. Furthermore, when I added `echo "$@"` within the function, it still prints as "Je suis".

How can I get the function to output the result for the whole string (with white space and new line characters), and not just the first word? Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `$*` -  `espeak -v fr --ipa "$*"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In bash, how do I join N parameters together as a space separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12283463/5291015)